# The operation couldn’t be completed. (SQLite.Result error 0.)

Tags: sqlite.swift

I am running into sporadic issues in production with SQLite.Swift where calls return the following SQLite.Result: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (SQLite.Result error 0.)".

A quick web search shows that others have been encountering that specific error as well.

Looking at the source of Result: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Sources/SQLite/Core/Result.swift

How is it possible that such an error gets thrown?
The initializer returns `nil` if the errorCode is `0` (aka `SQLITE_OK`). What am I missing there?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue out in production as well. Very sporadic. 

So far, I have been able to narrow it down to it occurring in one of these 3 calls:

try Blob(bytes: ...)
try conn.run(update)
try conn.run(insert)

Agreed that initializer should be returning nil in this case, unsure what is going on. Have you discovered anything new on this since last posting?